# zlib still check failed when install qemu

Tags: zlib, ubuntu-18.04, qemu, configure, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying to install qemu on my desktop using the wsl(win10, ubuntu 18.04). download the qemu from [here](https://github.com/mit-pdos/6.828-qemu.git%20qemu)

And try to configure like this:

```
./configure --disable-kvm --disable-werror --target-list="i386-softmmu x86_64-softmmu"
```

But it's always to throw out the zlib check failed error like this

> zlib check failed. Make sure to have the zlib libs and headers installed.

But I have already installed the zlib, and whereis also showed the zlib installed.

If I goto the configure file and disable the zlib test, it's going to throw out the 
"pthread check failed. Make sure to have the pthread libs and headers installed "

I really have nothing to do with this error. Could you help me out of this error?

Comment: I also tried

"sudo apt-get depmod qemu"
which I found it in stack overflow. But it shows
"Invalid operation depmod"

Comment: Why do you want to build and/or install qemu in the WSL? There are binaries for Windows which just run fine.

Comment: here is a mit lecture named 6.828 which needs a qemu(mit version). so it required here

Comment: Then I'd look for instructions to compile that qemu and/or the original qemu on Windows natively. Or set up a virtual machine (on an original qemu or Virtualbox) running a real Ubuntu and doing the task there. I'm not sure that it's worth to get this strange WSL to behave correctly.

Comment: Enough ranted. ;-) Where did you install zlib which is not found, in the Ubuntu of the WSL or in Windows? Did you install zlib-dev or just zlib?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install all the dependencies of QEMU (all the libraries it's going to use). If your WSL setup has the sources in its apt.conf then "apt-get build-dep qemu" will install what you need (this command says "install everything that would be needed to build the distro's package of QEMU", which is pretty much the same as for building upstream or some other version from source). Otherwise you can look at https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/Linux which suggests what packages to install. For building software, you can treat buliding on WSL like building on a real Ubuntu Linux.